In LyX is it possible to insert a PDF file but condense multiple PDF pages to a single compiled page in LyX?
In lyx I'm using the insert->file->external material and I chose the pdf options from pages 22-34 of some pdf, what I want to do is have every 4 pages (or some other number for example 6 or 2) of this pdf file compiled into a single page in the output (and order them top right -> top left -> bottom right -> bottom left).
I'm using Xetex, not sure if it's helpful

Except the right-to left ordering, there should be no problem.  Try it and see.

@JohnKormylo im asking because i don't know how to do it, if you know how I would love if you could explain

Well, it does have a manual which explains how to do it.  nup=2x2 will put 4 pages on each page.

To arrange the inserted pages of your PDF document add, e.g. nup=2x2 to the LaTeX and LyX Options tab, where you also have pages=22-34. Options are separated by comma, so you should have something like:
pages=22-34,nup=2x2

See the manual of package pdfpages for more information about option nup or how to add some space between the logical pages or a frame etc.
Note, that the preview in LyX usually differs from the PDF result in such cases. For example:
#LyX 2.4 created this file. For more info see https://www.lyx.org/
\lyxformat 620
\begin_document
\begin_header
\save_transient_properties true
\origin unavailable
\textclass article
\use_default_options true
\maintain_unincluded_children no
\language ngerman
\language_package default
\inputencoding utf8
\fontencoding auto
\font_roman "default" "default"
\font_sans "default" "default"
\font_typewriter "default" "default"
\font_math "auto" "auto"
\font_default_family default
\use_non_tex_fonts false
\font_sc false
\font_roman_osf false
\font_sans_osf false
\font_typewriter_osf false
\font_sf_scale 100 100
\font_tt_scale 100 100
\use_microtype false
\use_dash_ligatures true
\graphics default
\default_output_format default
\output_sync 0
\bibtex_command default
\index_command default
\float_placement class
\float_alignment class
\paperfontsize default
\use_hyperref false
\papersize default
\use_geometry false
\use_package amsmath 1
\use_package amssymb 1
\use_package cancel 1
\use_package esint 1
\use_package mathdots 1
\use_package mathtools 1
\use_package mhchem 1
\use_package stackrel 1
\use_package stmaryrd 1
\use_package undertilde 1
\cite_engine basic
\cite_engine_type default
\use_bibtopic false
\use_indices false
\paperorientation portrait
\suppress_date false
\justification true
\use_refstyle 1
\use_formatted_ref 0
\use_minted 0
\use_lineno 0
\index Index
\shortcut idx
\color #008000
\end_index
\secnumdepth 3
\tocdepth 3
\paragraph_separation indent
\paragraph_indentation default
\is_math_indent 0
\math_numbering_side default
\quotes_style english
\dynamic_quotes 0
\papercolumns 1
\papersides 1
\paperpagestyle default
\tablestyle default
\tracking_changes false
\output_changes false
\change_bars false
\postpone_fragile_content true
\html_math_output 0
\html_css_as_file 0
\html_be_strict false
\docbook_table_output 0
\docbook_mathml_prefix 1
\end_header

\begin_body

\begin_layout Standard
\begin_inset External
    template PDFPages
    filename example-image-a4-numbered.pdf
    extra LaTeX "pages=1-4,nup=2x2"

\end_inset


\end_layout

\end_body
\end_document

shows only page 1 in the editor window:

but in the PDF you have page 1—4 of the inserted PDF on a single page of the resulting document:

